# SharePoint Task list column naming

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-api

So I add a few columns via Web UI, I named them Number. When I list tasks in that list using `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}?expand=columns,items(expand=fields)` : I get:

```
...
   "items": [
    {
        ...
            "v2bs@odata.type": "#Single",
            "v2bs": 1,
            "_x0077_fx0@odata.type": "#Single",
            "_x0077_fx0": 2,
            "ziyy@odata.type": "#Single",
            "ziyy": 3,
            "m4l2@odata.type": "#Single",
            "m4l2": 4,
            "id": "1",
            "ContentType": "Task",
        ....
        }
    }
]
```

[image]

Every time there are different names, and also some of them are not allowed when I try to create a new task(`POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items`) with the same properties to the same list. Is this just a random naming? And how can I get the title of a column?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips. It isn't at all clear what you're trying to do, sample code showing how to reproduce the problem or even a clear description of which APIs you're using.

Answer (score 0):

If you create list columns in Quick Edit in list view page, the fields internal name will auto create by SharePoint server. So, I don't suggest you create list columns by this way.

I suggest you go to List Settings and create the list columns.